# Making pthread_rwlock_wrlock recursive

Tags: locking, pthreads, mutual-exclusion, rwlock

I have a problem regarding the behaviour of the pthread function [pthread_rwlock_wrlock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_rwlock_wrlock.html). The specification linked above states that when one thread has locked the lock for writing and the same thread locks it again, it results in undefined behaviour (I could actually observe this in that on x86 Linux calling this function is a noop and on PowerPC Linux it stalls the thread).

The behaviour I need would be a read write lock that has the following characteristics:

- read-locking by a thread succeeds if:

  - the lock is not held by any thread
  - the lock is only read-locked by zero or more threads (including the calling thread) and possibly read- or write locked by the calling thread
- write-locking succeeds when:

  - the lock is not held by any other thread
  - only the current thread is holding the lock (for reading or writing)

With a `pthread_mutex_t`, the recursiveness of the lock can be controlled via an initialization flag, but this is not possible for `pthread_rwlock_t`.

What are my options? I've never actually had to implement this kind of concurrency primitive in C, and I think I'm missing some obvious solution here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be honest, recursive locking does have some uses but generally it's a hack. I can't seem to find the article right now, but Butenhof has a nice rant on this.

Back to the question. You could keep a thread-specific flag that signals: "I have the lock". Set it right after locking and unset it before unlocking. Since this is the only thread accessing it, you should be safe. So when trying to lock you simply need to check: "Hey, is this thing locked already?".

As a side note: are you sure the design is okay if a thread tries to lock twice ?

#### EDIT

Found [the article](http://www.zaval.org/resources/library/butenhof1.html).

> But if that's all that's necessary, why does POSIX have recursive
> mutexes?
>
> Because of a dare.

Comment: What you say makes sense. Regarding the design, the issue I'm trying to solve is that I have some functions that modify parts of a structure (which are protected by the lock) and sometimes need to call these functions while protecting the whole structure. This might very well be not the optimal solution.

Comment: Adding your own metadata/stats around locks, including implementing your own lock count, is generally a win. It can allow you to answer useful questions such as how many times are locks being used, what's the average/maximal acquisition time, am I locking when already locked and where from, etc. This can give insight that's useful for tuning, as well as identifying unexpected behaviour that could be indicative of bugs or faulty design.