# Having multiple reader locks in a single thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-mutex, recursive-mutex, unique-lock

I have data coupled with a `Lock = boost::shared_mutex`.
I am *locking data access* with

*reader locks* `ReadLock = boost::shared_lock<Lock>`

**and** *writer locks* `WriteLock = boost::unique_lock<Lock>`.

Obviously, lots of readers may be reading the data at a time, and only one writing at it. But here's the catch:

A single thread may have **mutliple readlocks** on the same mutex, because it's calling functions that are locking the data themselves (with a `ReadLock`). But, as I have found, this causes inter-locking:

- Thread 1 read-locks data (Lock1)
- Thread 2 waits with a write-lock (LockW)
- Thread 1 spawns another read-lock (Lock2) while Lock1 is still alive

Now I get a lock because `Lock2` is waiting for `LockW` to exit, `LockW` is waiting for `Lock1`, and`Lock1` is stuck because of `Lock2`.

I don't know if it's possible to change the design so that each thread only does a single `ReadLock`. I believe that having a system that ***starves Writers*** would solve my issues. Is there a *common* way on how to handle my case?

Comment: i find it confusing that you talk in terms of locks. If they all lock the same mutex, then what is the problem?

Comment: @user463035818 You are right... I am calling the mutex a `Lock` because that's how it's named in the framework I am working on :-) But I have explained what's causing the lock-up in the bullet-list.

Comment: The common way is always lock mutexes in the same order... always.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125250/making-pthread-rwlock-wrlock-recursive

Comment: This is a standard deadlock scenario.  A ReaderWriterLock is one of the basic synchronization primitives, google can help you find one.  Also ensures that multiple threads can read concurrently, you don't have that right now.

Comment: Why do you think that "Lock2" is going to wait? As I understood it's a `shared_lock` and `Lock1` and `Lock2` lock the same `shared_mutex`. LockW will wait for Lock1 but Lock2 will succeed without waiting.

Comment: @BJovke That's what I thought too, but because Lock1 and Lock2 are in the same thread, and Lock1 outlives Lock2, there's chance that the deadlock described above will occur...

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior: `If lock_shared is called by a thread that already owns the mutex in any mode (exclusive or shared), the behavior is undefined.`.

Comment: It sounds like you calling a function that locks from within a function that has already acquired a lock?  If so, that will not work, as pointed out by SergeyA.